# How to get all documents of a collection with mongodb find() using webtask.io and mlab

Tags: mongodb, mlab, serverless, webtask, faas

I have a collection named "posts" in a mongodb at mlab.com and I am trying to access all of the documents in this collection with `db.collection('posts').find()`. Below is my code for my webtask I've created, which I named `mongodb_find`:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var waterfall   = require('async').waterfall;

/**
 * @param {secret} MONGO_URL - Mongo database url
 */
module.exports = function(ctx, cb) {

    var MONGO_URL = ctx.data.MONGO_URL;
    if (!MONGO_URL) return cb(new Error('MONGO_URL secret is missing'))

    waterfall([
        function connect_to_db(done) {
            MongoClient.connect(MONGO_URL, function(err, db) {
                if(err) return done(err);
                done(null, db);
            });
        },

        function find_hits(db, done) {
            db
            .collection('posts')
            .find(
                {},
                function (err, result) {
                    if(err) return done( err );
                    done( null, JSON.stringify(result) );
                }
            ).sort({ hits: -1 }).limit( 2 );
        }

    ], cb);

};
```

I have a `mongodb_upsert` webtask that is very similar to this and works perfectly. However, for my `mongodb_find` task I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "code": 400,
  "error": "Error when JSON serializing the result of the JavaScript code.",
  "details": "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "message": "Converting circular structure to JSON",
  "stack": "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON\n    at Object.stringify (native)\n    at /data/sandbox/lib/sandbox.js:775:48\n    at /data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:473:16\n    at next (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5315:29)\n    at /data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:958:16\n    at /data/io/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/webtask.js:27:6\n    at handleCallback (/data/_verquire/mongodb/2.0.48/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)\n    at Collection.find (/data/_verquire/mongodb/2.0.48/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:354:44)\n    at find_hits (/data/io/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/webtask.js:23:5)\n    at nextTask (/data/sandbox/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5310:14)"
}
```

When connecting to mongodb from the command line the same `find()` command works properly:

```
db.posts.find({}).sort({hits: -1}).limit(2);
```

The documents in the collection are set up like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a3ff239bda4eaa4ab96ef8b"
    },
    "title": "Testing 6",
    "url": "/jquery/2017/12/22/testing-6.html",
    "hits": 2
}
```

Does anyone know of a solution to this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Collection.find`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#find) returns a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html), not the results of the query. You probably want to chain all your operations such as `sort` and `limit` on the cursor, then use `toArray` to define the callback. [`toArray`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) will retrieve the results from the cursor.

For example:

```
function find_hits(db, done) {
  db.collection('posts')
    .find({})
    .sort({ hits: -1 })
    .limit(2)
    .toArray(function (err, result) {
      if(err) return done( err );
      done(null, JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}
```